# Apply MUI Theme to Created DOM Node

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am a huge fan of React-Material's theming feature and have used it extensively, but today I got stumped. To style popups with the theme, normally I stash the popup (with `display: none`) in my main component file like this:

```
function App() {

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Popup /> // ie here
      <LeftPanel />
      <Map />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

And then my themeProvider wraps the `<App/>`:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <App />
</ThemeProvider>
```

But *now* I'm trying to style a popup that is not inside `<App/>` and *not* on the DOM on load- I'm returning a node from `const node = document.createElement('div')`. Instead of the custom theme I created (let's say green for primary palette color), when I try to access theme inside `makeStyles`, it uses MUI's default theme (ie purple for default main palette color). I've tried exporting the custom `createMuiTheme` theme object from my `index` file and passing it to the popup component directly, but it keeps using MUI's default theme, ie:

Popup Button, where I'm trying to access my custom MUI theme:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
  return {
    text: {
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(14),
    },
    tab: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light
      // This comes back as the default MUI theme :(
    }
  }
});

interface PopupButtonProps { }

export const PopupButton: FunctionComponent<PopupButtonProps> = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={ `${classes.tab} 'custom-popup__view-details pointer'`}>
      <Typography variant='button' classes={{ root: classes.text}}>
        VIEW DETAILS
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Popup:

```
const Popup = (props: PopupProps) => {
  const node: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div');

  render(
    <>
      <div className="custom-popup__container">
        <PopupElement text={props.attributes.ServiceName} Icon={ProviderIcon} />
        <PopupElement text={props.attributes.Attribute_1} Icon={AddressIcon} />
        <PopupElement text={props.attributes.Attribute_2} Icon={PhoneIcon} />
      </div>
      <PopupButton />
    </>,
    node
  );
  return node;
}

export default Popup;
```

Does anyone out there have any ideas as to how to use a *specific* theme inside a component, ie maybe the `useTheme` hook to get a specific custom theme into a component?

```
Versions:
React: 16.13.1
MUI: 4.9.9 (I'll try upgrading to 4.9.11 in the meantime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you used `ThemeProvider` around `App`, you should use `ThemeProvider` in `Popup`:

```
import theme from "./whereever_you_define_your_theme_using_createMuiTheme";

const Popup = (props: PopupProps) => {
  const node: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div');

  render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className="custom-popup__container">
        <PopupElement text={props.attributes.ServiceName} Icon={ProviderIcon} />
        <PopupElement text={props.attributes.Attribute_1} Icon={AddressIcon} />
        <PopupElement text={props.attributes.Attribute_2} Icon={PhoneIcon} />
      </div>
      <PopupButton />
    </ThemeProvider>,
    node
  );
  return node;
}

export default Popup;
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan!! I had tried wrapping the button in `<ThemeProvider>` but that didn't work, so I didn't even bother wrapping the whole popup before- it works! 